# breaking down a JSON string and inputting values into MYSQL using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, mysql, node-red

I have had a read through of some of the questions but they are either written for a different language or written to be solved in a webpage,

Im using node-red to recieve BLE data but the data comes in 1 long string im recieving the following:

```
string
[{"timestamp":"2020-02- 
24T13:44:57Z","type":"Gateway","mac":"AC233FC02D95","gatewayFree":96,"gatewayLoad":0.08}
{"timestamp":"2020-02-24T13:44:59Z","type":"iBeacon","mac":"DB1265E96B6F","bleName":"","ibeaconUuid":"ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514   932AC01","ibeaconMajor":1,"ibeaconMinor":2,"rssi":-51,"ibeaconTxPower":-54,"battery":0}
{"timestamp":"2020-02-24T13:44:59Z","type":"iBeacon","mac":"F0728DEB0B9B","bleName":"","ibeaconUuid":"ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514932AC01","ibeaconMajor":5,"ibeaconMinor":1,"rssi":-30,"ibeaconTxPower":-62,"battery":0}]
```

my goal is to input the data into node-red in the following format

Gateway-Mac,IbeaconMinor,mac,rssi

i did previously use i different collector to gather data and it gave me the string in the following format

```
$GPRP,AC233FC02D95,FE2279DCB92B,-70,0201061AFF4C000215ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514932AC0100050003C2
```

which inputted collected BLE device DATA seperatly rather than in one long JSON string so it was easier to convert and input.

so my question is how can i either change it from

```
string
[{"timestamp":"2020-02- 
24T13:44:57Z","type":"Gateway","mac":"AC233FC02D95","gatewayFree":96,"gatewayLoad":0.08}
{"timestamp":"2020-02-24T13:44:59Z","type":"iBeacon","mac":"DB1265E96B6F","bleName":"","ibeaconUuid":"ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514   932AC01","ibeaconMajor":1,"ibeaconMinor":2,"rssi":-51,"ibeaconTxPower":-54,"battery":0}
{"timestamp":"2020-02-24T13:44:59Z","type":"iBeacon","mac":"F0728DEB0B9B","bleName":"","ibeaconUuid":"ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514932AC01","ibeaconMajor":5,"ibeaconMinor":1,"rssi":-30,"ibeaconTxPower":-62,"battery":0}]
```

to

```
string
[{"timestamp":"2020-02- 
24T13:44:57Z","type":"Gateway","mac":"AC233FC02D95","gatewayFree":96,"gatewayLoad":0.08}

{2020-02-24T13:44:59Z,DB1265E96B6F,ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514932AC01",1,2,-51,-54,0}

{2020-02-24T13:44:59Z,F0728DEB0B9B,ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514932AC01,5,1,-30,-62,0}]
```

or how can i input it into mysql in the following format
as mysql string

```
AC233FC02D95,F0728DEB0B9B51,1,-30
```

and

```
AC233FC02D95,DB1265E96B6F,2,-51
```

before changing hardware i inputted the string like so but with the new json format im not sure what to change in the code

GPRP,AC233FC02D95,FE2279DCB92B,-70,0201061AFF4C000215ACFD065EC3C011E39BBE1A514932AC0100050003C2

```
var raw = msg.payload;
msg.length = raw.length;
msg.raw = raw;
var data = {};

data.major = raw.slice(-10,-4);
data.mac = raw.substring(5,17);
data.hostname = raw.substring(18,30);
data.minor = raw.slice(-8,-4);
data.rssi = raw.substring(31,34)


var str = data.hostname;
var location = str.replace(`AC233FC02D95`, `PURPLE`)



var beacon = parseInt(data.minor ,16);



var msg = {
 topic : "INSERT INTO `test`.`track` (`location`,`beacon`, `mac`,`rssi`) 
VALUES ('"+location+"','"+beacon+"', '"+data.mac+"','"+data.rssi+"');"
}
return msg;
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thats the issue im not sure how to solve the problem I previously had a working solution but using different hardware ill post up what i previously had before changing hardware

Comment: mysql can save json, but higer versions have more functions for that. If you wnat the data seoerated in pho use json_decode to get an arrays and proceed from there lavascript has var obj = JSON.parse(text, function (key, value) {  choose one method and go for it.

Comment: okay i shall have a look at that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the msg with the string payload through the JSON node, it will parse it to an JSON object, you can then access the fields as normal.

Though from what you've posted the array entries look to be missing `,` separators.

From there you can build up what ever strings you want or insert the fields directly into the database.